# Run-length encoding in java

Tags: java, run-length-encoding

How to print out the number of a specific digit along with the digit itself in form "nxw." n is the frequency of the number, w is the number itself.

So, for example, if the user's input was 1 1 1. The output would be 3x1.

If the user's input was 1 1 1 at the first line and 7 7 1 1 0 at the second line. The output would be 3x1.2x7.2x1.1x0. with no spaces.

Note:

- loop ends with a dot.
- numbers don't have to be in a specific order
- user can input as many digits as they want.

So for example, Input can be 1 1 1 at the first line 7 7 1 1 0 at the second ... etc.

This is my code so far. But I know that it's not true.

```
import java.util.*;

public class LaufLaengenKodierung {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
    int freq = 0;
    int oldNum = 0;
    int num = 0;
    boolean first = true;
        
    while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
            
        int i = sc.nextInt();
            
        if(i == oldNum) {
                
            freq++;
            num = i;
                
        } else if(i != oldNum) {
                
            freq = 1;
            oldNum = i;
            num = i;
                
            if(first) {
                    
                first = false;
                num = i;
                freq = 1;
                    
            }
        }
    }
        
    System.out.print(freq + "x" + num + ".");
    sc.close();
}
        
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code specifically? Can you give an example where it fails, with input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: How do you know when the user has finished inputting integers?

Comment: Are the digits entered in a sorted order or can they be in any random order?

Comment: @Brian McCutchon If the input is 0 0 0 .. Output is 3x0. which is correct. BUT if the input 0 0 1 .. Output is 1x1. and if the input is 0 0 0 at the first line and 2 2 2 at the second, then the output is 3x2. When it should be 0x3.3x2.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc when the user enters "." or anything other than an integer

Comment: @Progman They can be in any order

Comment: @Ihab98 Please [edit] your question to include this information to your question. It is important to know that the digits can be random and are not necessary sorted in any way.

Comment: @Progman, this information is available in the initial post when OP described an input and expected output: _If the user's input was 1 1 1 at the first line and 7 7 1 1 0 at the second line. The output would be 3x1.2x7.2x1.1x0._

Comment: Lets clarify: @Ihab98 Is the input like "2 4 5 2 9 0 1 4" a valid possible sequence of digits which can be entered like that?

Comment: @Progman yes it is valid

Comment: @Ihab98 What would be the output generated by the input "2 4 5 2 9 0 1 4"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing code needs to be slightly refactored to print the frequency and integer value as soon as a sub-sequence of the same values ends.

```java
static void printRLE(String input) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
    int freq = 0;
    int oldNum = 0;
    boolean first = true;
        
    while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
            
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        
        if (i != oldNum || first) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else // integer value changed
                System.out.printf("%dx%d.", freq, oldNum);
            oldNum = i;
            freq = 1;
        } else {
            freq++;
        }
    }
    if (!first)    
        System.out.printf("%dx%d.%n", freq, oldNum);
    else 
        System.out.println("No integer found"); // or print 0x0 if it's correct
    sc.close();    
}
```

Tests:

```java
String[] tests = {
    "",
    "abc.",
    "11 11 11",
    "1 1 1\n7 7 1 1 0",
    "0 0 0",
};    

for (String test: tests) {
    System.out.println("test=[" + test + "]");
    printRLE(test);
    System.out.println("--------");
}
```

Output:

```
test=[]
No integer found
--------
test=[abc.]
No integer found
--------
test=[11 11 11]
3x11.
--------
test=[1 1 1
7 7 1 1 0]
3x1.2x7.2x1.1x0.
--------
test=[0 0 0]
3x0.
--------
```

---

**Update**
*If separate digits* need to be counted only (not the integer numbers), e.g. input `11 11 11` should be converted to `6x1.` instead of `3x11.` as shown above,  the method should be refactored to process the digits inside numbers:

```java
static void printRLEDigits(String input) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
    int freq = 0;
    int oldNum = 0;
    boolean first = true;
        
    out: while(sc.hasNext()) {
            
        String s = sc.next(); // getting "number" delimited with whitespaces
        for (char c: s.toCharArray()) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
                break out;
            }
            int i = c - '0';
            if (i != oldNum || first) {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else // digit changed
                    System.out.printf("%dx%d.", freq, oldNum);
                oldNum = i;
                freq = 1;
            } else {
                freq++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!first)    
        System.out.printf("%dx%d.%n", freq, oldNum);
    else 
        System.out.println("No integer found");
    sc.close();    
}
```

Output for tests: `"11 11 11", "112 223", "1 1 1\n7 7 1 1 0", "0 0 0"`:

```
test=[11 11 11]
6x1.
--------
test=[112 223]
2x1.3x2.1x3.
--------
test=[1 1 1
7 7 1 1 0]
3x1.2x7.2x1.1x0.
--------
test=[0 0 0]
3x0.
--------
```

[Online demo of both methods `printRLE` and `printRLEDigits`](https://ideone.com/M4HgMf)

Comment: the code has a bug. if the input was 1 1 1 on the first line and 7 7 2 2 1 on the second, the output is 3x1.2x7.2x2. which is not correct because it doesn't include the last digit which is one. so, in the end, there should be 1x1

Comment: Are you ready to bet on this?  [This demo](https://ideone.com/M4HgMf) among other tests prints the results of `"1 1 1\n7 7 2 2 1",` for both methods as `test=[1 1 1
7 7 2 2 1]
Numbers: 
3x1.2x7.2x2.1x1.
Digits: 
3x1.2x7.2x2.1x1.`

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the count of each individual digit. You can do this by creating an `int` array of size 10, for the digits `0` to `9`. Then it's a simple loop like

```
while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
        
    int i = sc.nextInt();
    
    countArray[i]++;
}
```

After that you check each element in the array and output the count of the digit, when it is bigger than 0. It can look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<countArray.length; i++) {
    if (countArray[i] > 0) {
        System.out.printf("%dx%d.", countArray[i], i);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you have to check if the number entered by the user is in the limit of 0 to 9, otherwise you run into `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s.